# Exclude Link to Certain Users PHP

Tags: php

I am still kind of new to PHP. How would I exclude an admin from my index.php (Presentation) file link. I know it's probably simple but I am unable to figure it out.

```
<div>
<?php
    if ($users['user_level'] == '0') {
    }
    if(loggedin()){
?>
    <a href="home.php">Home</a> |
    <a href="profile.php">Profile</a> |
    <a href="index.php">Presentation</a> |
    <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
<?php
    } else {
?>
    <a href="home.php">Home</a> |
    <a href="login.php">Login</a> |
    <a href="register.php">Register</a>
<?php       
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: what error u get ? and what is inside loggedin() function ?

Comment: you might want to store a `UserRole` in a session.....

Comment: I don't have any errors, I just want to have the index.php link not show for the Admin which has a `user_level` of 0. And I think I have user roles stored in my phpMyAdmin database.

Comment: My guess would be to say "if(loggedin() !== "admin"){". Or you could do a strcmp() call to the value returned by loggedin() or stricmp() or strstr() or stristr(). :-)

Comment: Use Roles table in db,this link explains it a lot, http://www.sitepoint.com/role-based-access-control-in-php/

Comment: @Karthikeyan : That is a great link! :-) +1 :-)

Comment: @Karthikeyan Thanks for the link but I already have users roles in my database.

Comment: @user6005619 : Then it should be really easy to just change the IF statement to reflect what or who you do not want to see whatever. :-)

Comment: Just use Javascript or php IF, to check the user role and display the link accordingly..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your set-up involves that an admin gets user_level equal to 0? If that's so, the code could be adapted a little to work:

```
<div>
    <?php
    if ($users['user_level'] == '0') {
        // if is admin, do nothing
    } elseif(loggedin()){
    ?>
        <a href="home.php">Home</a> |
        <a href="profile.php">Profile</a> |
        <a href="index.php">Presentation</a> |
        <a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
    <?php
    } else {
    ?>
        <a href="home.php">Home</a> |
        <a href="login.php">Login</a> |
        <a href="register.php">Register</a>
    <?php       
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Took me a while to figure out how to get it to connect, but works flawlessly. Thanks!